# Jquery .text() cannot break line

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is absolutely working fine but there is only problem is that `.text()` cannot break the line which comes from the database and all the result is in one line and in dialogue box already some white-space before my text start. I don't want to use `.html()` because its take all special character same as in my database.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var record;

    //set up the button styling and click functionality
    $('.editButton').button({
        icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-document"
        }
    }).click(function() {
        //set which record we're editing so we can update it later
        record = $(this).parents('.record');
        //populate the editing form within the dialog

        $('#Title').val(record.find('.sh_title').text());
        $('#Post').val(record.find('.sh_post').text());
        $('#PostId').val(record.find('.postid').text());

        //show the dialog
        $("#dialogContent").dialog("open");
    });    

    //set up the dialog box.
    $("#dialogContent").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            OK: function() {
                record.find('.sh_title').text($('#Title').val());
                record.find('.sh_post').text($('#Post').val());
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: use html() instead of.text()

Comment: i want to break the line like 1<br>2<br>3
result is 
1
2
3
but in dialogue box shows 123

Comment: and if there is some carriage return replace them with <br/>, use .html($('#Post').val().replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />'))

Comment: @ShailendraSharma using  html() having a problem and the problem is that suppose in my database special characters is saved and all characters are shown in dialogue box and i want to show html decoded characters

Comment: hey @aprovent in which line i can use

Comment: #post is two times written then where should i replace

Comment: it must be used everywhere you read a database record string that is multiline.

Comment: $('#Post').val(record.find('.sh_post').text()); please edit this line

Comment: @aprovent help me i m very new in jquery

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/patelmit69/mLqowd7f/2/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var record;

    //set up the button styling and click functionality
    $('.editButton').click(function () {
        //set which record we're editing so we can update it later
        record = $(this).parents('.record');
        //populate the editing form within the dialog

        $('#Title').val(cleanText(record.find('.sh_title').html()));
        $('#Post').val(cleanText(record.find('.sh_post').html()));
        $('#PostId').val(cleanText(record.find('.postid').html()));
      
           
     
        //show the dialog
       // $("#dialogContent").dialog("open");
        return false;
    });

    //set up the dialog box.
    $("#dialogContent").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            OK: function () {
                record.find('.sh_title').text($('#Title').val());
                record.find('.sh_post').text($('#Post').val());
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});


function cleanText(text){debugger;
text = text.replace(/<\/p>/mg, "<br></p>");
text = text.replace(/<\/div>/mg, "<br></div>");
text = text.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/mg, "\n");
text = text.replace(/<p/mg, "<br><p");
text = text.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/mg, "\n");
text = text.replace(/  /mg, " ");
text = text.trim();
text = htmlDecode(text);                         
                         
var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
                         
return text.replace(regex, "");
}

function htmlDecode(input){
  var e = document.createElement('div');
  e.innerHTML = input;
  return e.innerText;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr class='record'>
        <td class='sh_title'> Title</td>
        <td class='sh_post'> this is the content  <br/> new one</td>
        <td class='postid'> 1</td>
        <td><a class='editButton' href="">Edit</a> </td>

    </tr>
    <tr class='record'>
        <td class='sh_title'> Title 2</td>
        <td class='sh_post'> this is the content 2  <br/> new one <br /> Line 2</td>
        <td class='postid'> 2</td>
        <td><a class='editButton' href="">Edit</a> </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>><td>Post Title</td><td><textarea id='Title'></textarea></td></tr>
    <tr>><td>Desc</td><td><textarea id='Post'></textarea></td></tr>
    <tr>><td>Id</td><td><textarea id='PostId'></textarea></td></tr>
</table>
```

When you using the html input tag then it is for the the single line input that's why it will not display more then one line in text box,

If you want to show more then one line then change the input tag to textarea then it will work for you.

Comment: Ok so what is the html ?

Comment: any help of yours,its precious for me

Comment: Can i have HTML content?

Comment: where can i send you html , in comment there is more enough word says

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93688/discussion-between-amy-and-mitul).